# не высвечивает список в форме!

Tags: javascript, html5, form

подскажите пожалуйста
у меня есть форма внутри которой один инпут и кнопка "добавить"...
без формы все работает,я нажимаю кнопку добавить и элемент добавляется в лист!
как только я создаю форму, при нажатии кнопки я вижу что элемент каким-то образом добавляется и моментально пропадает!
вот мой HTML:

```
<form id="zip">
<input type="text" id="candidate"/>
<button type="submit" class="btnAdd" onclick="addItem()">Add</button>      
<ul id="places"></ul>
</form>
```

в ul id places должны вписываться эти инпуты!

вот еще мой js!

```
function addItem(){
var ul = document.getElementById("places");
var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
var li = document.createElement("li");
var btn = document.createElement("button");

btn.onclick = function() {
var ul = document.getElementById("places");
var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
var item = document.getElementById(candidate.value);
ul.removeChild(item); 
ul.removeChild(btn);
}

var t = document.createTextNode("delete");
btn.appendChild(t);
btn.className = "btnDelete";
document.body.appendChild(btn);
li.setAttribute('id',candidate.value);
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(candidate.value));
ul.appendChild(li);
ul.appendChild(btn);
}

var form = document.getElementById("zip");
form.reset();
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так происходит потому, что браузер по умолчанию отправляет форму на сервер, тем самым перезагружая страницу (или загружает новую). Для отмены действия браузера существует стандартный метод event.preventDefault().

Используйте следующий код.

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="btnAdd" onclick="addItem(event)">Add</button>
```

Javascript

```
function addItem(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // остальной код
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!работает!

Answer (score 0):

Зачем нужна форма?

```
<button type="button" ...
```

По нажатию кнопки с `type="submit"` происходит стандартная отправка формы, и страница перезагружается. Поменяйте тип кнопки или возвращайте `false` из обработчика.

```
 ... onclick="addItem(); return false;" ...
```

Comment: так по заданию необходимо...